# how to auto scroll, scroll in view pager with circular dots

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on this issue for over 10 hours and its pushing me hard,

I need a library, which has circular dots, auto scroll, infinite scroll and I will provide title of the picture below it, I checked all the libraries provided so far and they did not help me, is there a library you guys use so far ? thank you

Comment: I made something very similar with a combination of infiniteViewPager and android-wheel librarys

Comment: @Nanoc how did you do it :) do you have the code ? thanks

Comment: Was a hard way, im sorry but i cant post the code to you. but i can tell you that the hard part is making the infiniteScrollView, a page indicator and the auto-scroll are the easy part.

Comment: That was helpful, I will tell my client what you said, uuh, " infinitescrollview is hard, so do it yourself "

Comment: Its hard so it should be taken in account that it will draw a lot of work time, just told you that there are third-party library that already do that but probably not exactly the way you want so modifying it can be a hell.

Comment: I did it, did not test it carefully but it looks that it is working

Comment: https://github.com/ajaydewari/AutoSlideViewpager

Answer (score 4):

for circular indicators you can make use of this library :
https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

and for autoscrollview you can use this library :
https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager

I am using these two in my projects. make use of the github samples. it will help you for implementation details

Answer (score 3):

Instead of finding libraries for this, implement the code that I am attaching below. Your dots view, auto scroll and infinite scroll will work with it. For the name of the image you can add code in the onPageChangeListener method to show the name of the image

[View Pager Example for You](http://bit.ly/1PAgmeo)

Hope your issue is resolved using this example that I made for you

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, but thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ohh then there might be a misunderstanding there cause what I implemented after reading your question was a viepager which will have dots at the bottom depicting the page on which we are present and automatic scrolling after a fixed interval and which starts all over again once all the images are scrolled

Comment: Pleasure @muoki_D

Comment: Pleasure @bdevloper

Comment: bro, after last page it goes back to first page by passing all in between, can't   it be a circular one?

Comment: @AnandKumar - Brother, that is how the circle works in the sense once the last image aurfaces, the whole cycle begins again. Please correct me if I am missing out on your query based on which I can have the answer sent